# Download file without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript page it has a table that has certain details. on click of a row, it will download a JSON file. I am able to download the file but the page refreshes after the download.

```js
function testDownload() {
  const data = { a: "ajith", b: "kumar" };
  const dataStr =
    "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
  const downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement("a");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  debugger;
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("id", "anchor");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "extracted" + ".json");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
  downloadAnchorNode.click();
}
```

How to restrict the page refresh after the download has completed?

Comment: add `return false` at the bottom of function

Comment: @AkashShrivastava, please explain that why he has to add `return false`?

Comment: `downloadAnchorNode.onclick=function() { testDownloadFun(event); return false }` and make sure testDownLoad is not called from a submit event

Comment: @AhmedsaysReinstateMonica `downloadAnchorNode.click();` would invoke a browser redirect, but return false here would work same as `e.preventDefault` and cancel the redirect event

Comment: Sorry, the testDownloadFun() doesn't have any impact on the code I added it for testing purpose. I tried preventDefault function but the download is not getting started.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on a button to download the JSON, try this code:

```
function testDownload(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = { a: "ajith", b: "kumar" };
  const dataStr =
    "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
  const downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement("a");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  debugger;
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("id", "anchor");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("onclick", "testDownloadFun(event)");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "extracted" + ".json");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
  downloadAnchorNode.click();
}
```

I added the "preventDefault" method.

Comment: No it prevents implementing the default function for each element:
for example Toggling a checkbox is the default action of clicking on a checkbox. This method demonstrates how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: It doesn't work because there is another click event trigger after that downloadAnchorNode.click(); I have to prevent defaults of that click event and also to download the file. is there any way to accomplish this

Comment: How about adding "type='button'" attribute to your button HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

My situation is that the page will jump/change to another site.
In my case, it needs to be changed like this:

```
function testDownload() {
  const data = { a: "ajith", b: "kumar" };
  const dataStr =
    "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
  const downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement("a");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  debugger;
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("id", "anchor");
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "extracted" + ".json");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox

  downloadAnchorNode.onclick = (e) => { // Add this
      e.stopPropagation();
  }

  downloadAnchorNode.click();
}
```

My reason is probably that the click event bubbled up on two ancestor elements, `<body> or <document>`. Triggers event listener bound to one of its two elements.